# In Pandas, how do I breakdown human readable format of time into different units like days, hours, minutes, and seconds using Regex?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

On a dataframe, I have a column of duration in a human-readable format like "29 days 4 hours 32 minutes 1 second". I want to break them down by having columns of days, hours, minutes, seconds with the values derived from the duration column. Like 29 for days, 4 for hours, 32 minutes, and 1 for seconds. I've already used this but it's not working correctly:

```
# Use regex to extract time values into their respective columns
new_df = df['duration'].str.extract(r'(?P<days>\d+(?= day))|(?P<hours>\d+(?= hour))|(?P<minutes>\d+(?= min))|(?P<seconds>\d+(?= sec))')
```

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import re

list = {'id': ['123','124','125','126','127'],
        'date': ['1/1/2018', '1/2/2018', '1/3/2018', '1/4/2018','1/5/2018'],
        'duration': ['29 days 4 hours 32 minutes',
                     '1 hour 23 minutes',
                     '3 hours 2 minutes 1 second',
                     '4 hours 46 minutes 22 seconds',
                     '2 hours 1 minute']}

df = pd.DataFrame(list)

# Use regex to extract time values into their respective columns
new_df = df['duration'].str.extract(r'(?P<days>\d+(?= day))|(?P<hours>\d+(?= hour))|(?P<minutes>\d+(?= min))|(?P<seconds>\d+(?= sec))')
```

Results in the following dataframe:

[image: The new dataframe only has the first value but not the rest. It captured the 29 for days, and 1, 3, 4, 2, for minutes but the subsequent columns values are NaNs.]

The new dataframe only has the first value but not the rest. It captured the 29 for days, and 1, 3, 4, 2, for minutes but the subsequent columns values are NaNs.

Ideally, the dataframe should like this below:

[image: Ideal DataFrame, what I would like it to look like.]

I have a feeling something is wrong with my regex. Should I not use the "|" to separate the groups? Any help or nudge in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my approach with `extractall` instead of `extract`:

```
# same pattern as yours
# can replace this with a for loop
pattern = ( '(?P<days>\d+)(?= days?\s*)|'        # days
          + '(?P<hours>\d+)(?= hours?\s*)|'      # hours
          + '(?P<minutes>\d+)(?= minutes?\s*)|'  # minutes
          + '(?P<seconds>\d+)(?= seconds?\s*)'   # seconds
          )

(df.duration.str.extractall(pattern)   # extract all with regex
  .reset_index('match',drop=True)      # merge the matches of the same row
  .stack()
  .unstack(level=-1, fill_value=0)     # remove fill_value if you want NaN instead of 0
)
```

Output:

```
  days hours minutes seconds
0   29     4      32       0
1    0    12      23       0
2    0     3       2       1
3    0     4      46      22
4    0     2       1       0
```

Answer (score 3):

Your string format is matched with `pd.Timedelta` string specs. Just convert it directly to `Timedelta` and call its attribute `components`

```
df_final = (df.duration.map(pd.Timedelta)
              .dt.components[['days','hours','minutes','seconds']])
```

Or

```
df_final = (pd.to_timedelta(df.duration)
              .dt.components[['days','hours','minutes','seconds']])

Out[258]:
   days  hours  minutes  seconds
0    29      4       32        0
1     0      1       23        0
2     0      3        2        1
3     0      4       46       22
4     0      2        1        0
```